# Why is the default cache expires header Thu, 01 Dec 1994 16:00:00 GMT? What is the significance of this date?

Tags: caching, http-headers, websphere

When some requests are processed via WebSphere application server, it sets a cache expires header of Thu, 01 Dec 1994 16:00:00 GMT. This date seems to be in a lot of documentation as a example of a properly formed date for an expires header, but it is also all over the internet in regards to actual responses. Where does this exact date (Thu, 01 Dec 1994 16:00:00 GMT) originate from?

Is this what happens when you do `response.setHeader("Expires",0)` is this the default value?

Comment: The HTTP date format, for some reason unknown to me, includes the day of the week so calculating a date in the past, implying 'do not cache', is not completely trivial. So, people use the spec date.

Answer (score 6):

I don't think there is any particular significance, beyond its appearing as the example 'expires' date in [RFC 1945: *Hypertext Transfer Protocol -- HTTP/1.0*](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1945.txt) dated May 1996.  At least some of the text would have been written much earlier, indeed RFC 1738: *Uniform Resource Locators (URL)* is dated December 1994.

At the time of writing it would have been a reasonable example value.  In the same way the 'date' header example in the RFC 'Tue, 15 Nov 1994 08:12:31 GMT', is prevalent in the web.  The two values together form a consistent example.

In RFC 1945 there's no mention of a specific default value, however it states

> Note: Applications are encouraged to
>   be tolerant of bad or
>         misinformed implementations of the Expires header. A value of zero
>         (0) or an invalid date format should be considered equivalent to
>         an "expires immediately." Although these values are not
>   legitimate
>         for HTTP/1.0, a robust implementation is always desirable.

Implementors of servers will have read the RFC - they'd need to in order to know what to implement - and picked up the example date given, and used it.

Comment: Hmmmm but why do so many responses from WebSphere and other web servers contain "Expires: Thu, 01 Dec 1994 16:00:00 GMT". This date must be set by something somewhere (eg a Method that returns that as the default expiry date for a date in the past). If you search google for that date you can see that many other people get responses that contain "Expires: Thu, 01 Dec 1994 16:00:00 GMT". I do not believe that it is a coincidence.

Comment: @Jake - I'm not saying it's coincidental.  The authors of WebSphere and other web servers will have seen the date in the RFC and used it to s
ignify "expires immediately".  What you say is therefore true - it is coded in those apps.  I've added a note on this to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can check [this 30 seconds](https://youtu.be/TNlcoYLIGFk?t=480) to see why it is like that. It's basically copy and pasted value from technical documentation.